# How to remove case sensitivity from email in js

Tags: javascript, email, case-insensitive

I want to remove the case sensitivity from emails when searching emails.
For further explanation, If I search an email(`dmc@gmail.com`) in a different ways like this `'DMC@gmail.com'` or `'dMc@gmail.com'` or `'Dmc@gmail.com'`. I want to retrieve the email. If anyone can help, really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: lowercase all letters in searching string and compare it with lowercase of string. Simple

Comment: Are you performing the search from a database ? Or are you doing an in memory lookup ?

Comment: from a database

Comment: Further to first comment then, database may have a function such as  `lower()`. It may mess up index use though so possibly not a good approach in a big table that is indexed on email address

Comment: I would explore the possibility to perform a case insensitive search in your database of choice. Which database are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Oracle db @EnricoMassone

Comment: @ddmmcc I'm not an expert on oracle db but I would suggest to investigate the possibility to perform a case insensitive search for strings in the oracle db.

Comment: Yes, I have used that way to remove case sensitivity. Thanks @EnricoMassone.

Comment: @ddmmcc I have added an answer to be used as a reference for future readers of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this email lookup operation is actually done by querying an Oracle database.

In this case I would suggest to investigate whether it is possible to execute a query containing a case insensitive `WHERE` clause to filter on the `Email` column. I'm not an oracle db expert, but usually database systems allow to perform case insensitive queries, by using the proper collation. At least checkig if this is actually allowed is worth the effort.

By doing so you will get the following advantages:

- the actual computation is done on the database, so you are basically avoiding computation at the application level. Databases are highly optimazed for this kind of work and can leverage indexes to speed up the filtering
- you will move less data on the network, because only the records which actually match your filter criteria will be transferred over the network to the machine running your application

Another option you can consider, if running a case insensitive query is not supported by your database, is storing the email in a normalized form. You can save both the actual email value (with the original casing) and a normalized version of the email (for instance you can use the email value transformed in uppercase). Then, to perform case insensitive search, you can use the column containing the normalized email value in your `WHERE` clause. **I would suggest to use this approach as a last resort**, because you will increase the amount of data stored and you will make your queries less obvious: this is just a workaround to apply when case insensitive queries are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `toLowerCase()` in js and you'r done.

```js
let text0 = "abc@gmail.com";
let text1 = "aBc@gmail.com";
let text2 = "ABC@gmail.com";

text0 = text0.toLowerCase();
text1 = text1.toLowerCase();
text2 = text2.toLowerCase();


console.log(text0, text1, text2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve that you could get the text value from the search input and transform it to lowercase before executing the search, you can do that in JS with the method [yourText]`.toLowerCase()`

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript String to lowercase</h1>

<input id="your-input" type="text">

<button onclick="convertText()">To lowercase!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function convertText() {
let text = document.getElementById("your-input").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.toLowerCase();    
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

```
<input id="text_inp" type="text" />
<script>
document.getElementById('text_inp').oninput = function () {
  this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
};
</script>
```